# Want to stop subdirectory from showing in urls

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've read a lot of threads on this topic, but I'm not very proficient at this stuff and nothing has worked for me.

I installed Wordpress in a sub directory and:

1. Changed the site address URL to the main domain in WordPress.
2. Then I copied the `.htaccess` and `index.php` to the root directory.
3. Then I changed the `index.php` file so that the require(‘wp/wp-blog-header.php’) pointed to the subdirectory.

Everything works, except the subdirectory shows in the URL, which I would like to hide.

The subdirectory I installed to is 'NA20H'. After changing the `index.php` file to point to it, this is what I have.

The `.htaccess` file in the Root directory reads:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /NA20H/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /NA20H/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the `.htaccess` in the subdirectory reads:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /NA20H/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /NA20H/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What do I need to do in order to get 'NA20H' to stop showing in the URLs?
Thank you.

Comment: No need to copy index.php to the root dir.Pls explain the directory structure clearly.

Comment: I followed a tutorial I found for installing WordPress in a subdirectory, but making it look like it was on the root.

Comment: So for example my site is at examplestie.com but I installed WP in a subdirectroy called 'NA20H'. The tutorial said to copy the .htaccess and the index file to the root and change to index file to point to the subdirectory so that's what I did. But now every link shows 'NA20H' in the url. For example my about page shows examplesite.com/NA20H/about. I don't want the 'NA20H' to show in the url. I also have the Yoast SEO installed don't know it that is causing a problem here.

Comment: So the WP files are in /NA20H/wp/ , right?

Comment: My apologies. No, I installed all of the WP in the NA20H subdirectory. I downloaded WP, created a folder called 'NA20H' and copied all of the files directly into the NA20H folder using FileZilla. So the actual path is like this: mysite.com/NA20H. So if I go to the about page it will read 'mysite.com/NA20H/about, but I want the 'NA20H' NOT to show. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need to copy index.php to root. Just follow these steps.
Put this in the .htaccess in the root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ NA20H/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ NA20H/$1 [L]
```

Put this in .htaccess in the NA20H folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /NA20H/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work. Is it possible a plugin could be an issue? I have Yoast SEO and W3 Total Cache installed on the site.